# Wi-Fi passphrase changed overnight—bug or attack?

Tags: attacks, router

This morning I discovered that the WPA-Personal passphrase of my residential ISP–provided wireless router had been truncated to the first 3 characters. Everything else in its configuration appeared to be in working order, and upon reentering the complete passphrase all clients were able to automatically reassociate.

What would cause that to happen? Is it likely to be just a bug in the router, or might it be a symptom of more nefarious activity? I'm not sure if I should just go on with my day or treat the device as compromised.

---

Details:

- The settings for remote administration via Telnet, SSH, and HTTP were and remain disabled.
- The administration password is a unique password that I set upon receiving the device.
- A 3-character WPA-Personal passphrase is invalid and should be unusable.

Comment: Is there an option in the router's configuration settings to enable remote administration?  If so, do you know if this option was enabled before and/or if it is enabled now?

Comment: The settings for remote administration via Telnet, SSH, and HTTP were and remain disabled.

Comment: In that case, the change must have been made from a device connected to the local network.  Was the admin password changed when the router was setup, or was it still set to the default?

Comment: It could be either one.  Does it really matter though?  Either way your wireless router isn't acting as expected with regard to security.  I'd replace it with a different device entirely (preferably an OSS like dd-wrt), or, if it's supported, flash the firmware to an OSS firmware.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think we can tell from here. I would strongly suspect any in-house activity though, maybe somebody was fed up with the long passphrase. Time to upgrade your software, reset the router and start over again with new, stronger passphrases. Looking up existing vulnerabilities would not be a bad idea too.